# Jupyter Notebook on AWS hangs

Tags: amazon-web-services, jupyter-notebook

I followed the [instructions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dlami/latest/devguide/setup-jupyter.html8/run-jupyter-notebook-on-server) on how to setup jupyter on a AWS instance, but am unable to access it from my personal computer at the address https://127.0.0.1:8157 after setting up the ssh tunnel and starting the notebook.  It just hangs.  Anyone have ideas on how to fix.

I used the following security settings

[image]

I opened a tunnel as so

> ssh -i keypair.pem -L 8157:127.0.0.1:8888 ubuntu@

and ran the instance as

> $ jupyter notebook
>   [I 03:59:30.778 NotebookApp] Serving notebooks
>   from local directory: /home/ubuntu/qlearning [I 03:59:30.778
>   NotebookApp] 0 active kernels  [I 03:59:30.779 NotebookApp] The
>   Jupyter Notebook is running at:
>   http://localhost:8888/?token=4b35857968acb4a75dc4b7fdd246c20b967dcfaaa13799c2
>   [I 03:59:30.779 NotebookApp] Use Control-C to stop this server and
>   shut down all kernels (twice to skip confirmation). [W 03:59:30.779
>   NotebookApp] No web browser found: could not locate runnable browser.
>   [C 03:59:30.779 NotebookApp]
>
> ```
> Copy/paste this URL into your browser when you connect for the first time,
> to login with a token:
>     http://localhost:8888/?token=4b35857968acb4a75dc4b7fdd246c20b967dcfaaa13799c2
> ```

But both https://127.0.0.1:8157/ and https://127.0.0.1:8157/?token=4b35857968acb4a75dc4b7fdd246c20b967dcfaaa13799c2 hang.

Comment: What do you mean by hang? White screen?  Page Keeps loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use **http**://127.0.0.1:8157 not https://

*There's no need to open port 8888 in the security group, as you are tunneling the connection through port 22.